# Bootstrap: How can I use switch tabs from the menu bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have built justified tabs in my body. The same tabs are sub menus(dropdown) in the navigation menu. How can I switch the tabs directly from the menu when I click a dropdown?

Here is the code I tried. 
This is the navigation menu.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#letenky" data-toggle="tab">EMPRESA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hotel" data-toggle="tab">CLIENTES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#auto" data-toggle="tab">NA MÍDIA</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the code for the tabs normally.

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li><a href="#letenky" data-toggle="tab">
        <p>EMPRESA</p>
    </a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#hotel" data-toggle="tab">
        <p>CLIENTES</p>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#auto" data-toggle="tab">
        <p>NA MÍDIA</p>
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

For reference, this is the final layout. http://aijaz.co/angloamerican/clientes.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `data-toggle="tab"` attribute to your links:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#letenky" data-toggle="tab">EMPRESA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hotel" data-toggle="tab">CLIENTES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#auto" data-toggle="tab">NA MÍDIA</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**

Based on the comments below, it would be a better approach to use javascript:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function() {
    $('#tabs').find('a[href='+$(this).prop("href")+']').click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have tried that, but just the body of the tab changes, and not the main tab head..

Comment: Isn't this what you asked for? :)

Comment: I did. But when the tab changes, even its head should be changing right, and that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Buddy, that changes the body of the tabs only, and not the header. :(